# Spark SQL error read JSON file : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to read JSON file using Spark SQL in Java.
this is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
...
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.jsonFile("~/test.json");
df.printSchema();
df.registerTempTable("test");
...
```

i made simple JSON "test.json", to make it simple:

```
{
   "name": "myname"
}
```

and when i tried to run the code, it comes error message:

```
efg
17/03/30 10:02:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.6.86.82:36824 with 1948.2 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.6.86.82, 36824)
17/03/30 10:02:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.6.86.82, 36824)
17/03/30 10:02:26 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.CaseInsensitiveMap.<init>(ddl.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:697)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.jsonFile(SQLContext.scala:572)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.jsonFile(SQLContext.scala:553)
at sugi.kau.sparkonjava.SparkSQL.main(SparkSQL.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more
17/03/30 10:02:26 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the docs spark for the function jsonFile(String path):
Loads a JSON file (one object per line), returning the result as a DataFrame. (Note tha jsonFile is replaced by read().json())

so you should have an object per line and your source file should be like this :

```
  {"name": "myname"}
  {"name": "myname2"}
  .....
```

Comment: i changed my json file as what you said
but, the error message is still remain

i am using spark 2.11
there is no .read() in SQLContext, only .jsonFile

Comment: you mean spark 2.1.0 ?  in this version you have the method read http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets

Comment: thanks for your response. i got the point. i was using old way to get spark connection with sparkconf, javasparkcontext, sqlcontext. with the new one _sparkSession_ method read is available. now, reading JSON file is working fine